# bind9 configuration file PROBLEM

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, dns, bind

I have a pc with **debian 9 stretch** and a router (Nano Pi r4s with **openwrt**) both with **bind9**. I have set the `min-cache-ttl` parameter of **80000** seconds on **debian stretch**, and when i try to set it also on the **nano pi**, it tells me that the maximum can reach **90** seconds !! How is it possible? How can I set a higher value ?? Thank you

**debian 9** (*`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`*):

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-transfer { none; };
        dump-file  "/var/cache/bind/cache.db";
        notify no;
        allow-notify { none; };
        forward only;

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation no;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        attach-cache yes;
        min-cache-ttl  86400;
        max-cache-ttl  87000;
        max-cache-size 1024M;
};
```

**Nano PI R4S** (*`/etc/bind/named.conf`*):

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dump-file "/var/cache/bind/cache.db";
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-transfer { none; };
        notify no;
        allow-notify { none; };
        forward only;

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        dnssec-validation no;
        attach-cache yes;
        min-cache-ttl  80000; ## ERROR! Max is 90!
        max-cache-ttl  43200;
        max-cache-size 1024M;
};
```

Comment: 90 seconds seems to be the maximum value for `min-cache-ttl` described in [the configuration reference](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_17_10/reference.html#tuning)...which also says, "*...and is truncated to 90 seconds if set to a greater value.*".Are you using the same version of bind9 on both platforms?

Comment: @larsks no...bind9 in debian stretch have 9.10..bind9 in openwrt is 9.14...

Comment: In any case, it seems the solution is to set `min-cache-ttl` to a valid value.

Comment: yes, but i didn't understand why I can't set a higher value! How is it possible that in the previous version I could do it while in this new one I could not? Is there another way to set a higher value?

Comment: Because the previous version, as described in the documentation, would truncate it to 90 seconds. So in *neither* case are you able to set it to a higher value: it's just that in one version is silently truncated, and in the other version you get an explicit error message.

Comment: so, isn't there a way to preserve cached entries longer?

Comment: Forcing such a high `min-cache-ttl` would cause you problems with cloud services that use DNS-based load balancing: for example, the standard TTL for `www.google.com` is less than 200 seconds. If the Google node that serves you becomes overloaded or needs maintenance, they switch the DNS information to point to another node, wait 200 or so seconds (maybe x2 to account for strange configs) and then can take the original node offline. If you force a min-cache-ttl of 80000, in that situation `www.google.com` may be "down" for you for up to 79600 seconds or so.

Comment: 80000 seconds was just an example ... then obviously it will have to be adjusted to my needs. But the point is if you can do it in bind9 ...

Comment: My guess Debian 9 has its own patch before this feature merged into upstream version. And ISC better now what min-cache-ttl value should be. Thats why they are different.
https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/613
https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/commit/c59f332db2914940f0ea80021647204ed24579f5
http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/b/bind9/unstable_changelog

Comment: The DNS is designed so that the authoritative DNS server sets the TTL for normal (positive) caches. The `min-cache-ttl` and `max-cache-ttl` just set lower and upper bounds for what those TTLs can be. Restricting `max-cache-ttl` to lower than the authoritative server says just causes some extra queries; restricting with `min-cache-ttl` to higher than the authoritative server says makes your cache sometimes pass off stale data as supposedly valid. In your Nano PI R4S example you're trying to set the min-cache-ttl higher than max-cache-ttl, which is just nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I set a higher value ?

**Get bind-9.14 sources, change the value of the `MAX_MIN_CACHE_TTL` and compile the bind package for yourself**

> How is it possible?

**Debian**
Before bind-9.13 Debian had their own patch `0003-Add-min-cache-ttl-and-min-ncache-ttl-keywords.patch` that added `min-cache-ttl` feature to their bind package.

**Obviously the maximum value for `min-cache-ttl` was > 90s since there is no checks here** https://sources.debian.org/patches/bind9/1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.3+deb9u6/10_min-cache-ttl.diff/#L30

With bind-9.13 Debian removes http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/b/bind9/unstable_changelog
there patch since upstream already ported this feature in that version.

**OpenWRT**
OpenWRT compiles there bind package directly from ISC source files.
Here makefile https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/master/net/bind/Makefile

```
PKG_VERSION:=9.18.4
PKG_SOURCE_URL:= \
    https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/$(PKG_VERSION) \
    https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/$(PKG_VERSION)
```

Also for bind-9.14.2
https://github.com/openwrt/packages/commit/868f29d4ee61205e65994f67f23a02198a9dea33#diff-eb969664858d3b384948d5ecec074c7cf894444a8e293aebb09d21720a00f5b5

In bind  `min-cache-ttl` was added at Nov 14, 2018 and released in version 9.13.4
commit https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9/commit/e9a939841dcf37021aab189caee836bfb59b45dc

`min-cache-ttl` max value defined here
https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9/commit/e9a939841dcf37021aab189caee836bfb59b45dc?diff=unified#diff-d67681a4334d52b7a3e6aa8ff9a56072834cf2f4e5158cbfd4cb3b232c731bf7R24

```
#define MAX_MIN_CACHE_TTL 90
```

https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9/commit/e9a939841dcf37021aab189caee836bfb59b45dc?diff=unified#diff-d6bb5d421804dd0a1b7bd92dcd1f76348321360d9dbf5512257c4753cc815443R972

```
static intervaltable intervals[] = {
...
    { "min-cache-ttl", 1, MAX_MIN_CACHE_TTL },  /* 90 secs */
...
};
```

**So in the bind and therefore in openwrt the maximum value for `min-cache-ttl` was always 90 from the very beginning.**

Comment: Thanks very much!